# auto refresh the page html generated by a caching system in php

Tags: php, html, caching

So I just found out the establishment of a system cache in php, but I need to understand one thing . I have an `index.php` file and I included this file has two files `cache-top.php` and `cache-bottom.php` and I generate an `index.html` file , I also change the name of my file `index.php` in `first.php` to fall on the `index.html` page when you enter the site. The system works well because I have a file that is generated, but I feel that the index.html file does not change after 2min as I configured in the "cache -top" file for refresh the content of `index.html` must refresh the page `first.php` and wanted to know if this is normal ? and what is a solution for the `index.html` file to refresh its content without refreshing `first.php` ?

**cache-top.php code :**

```
$expireTime = time () -120 ;
$caching = FALSE ;

$cacheFile = "index.html";

If( file_exists($cacheFile) ) {
    if (filemtime($cacheFile) < $expireTime) {
        ob_start();
    } else {      
        $caching = TRUE ;
         readfile($cacheFile);
    }
} else {
    ob_start() ;
}
```

thank you in advance